# jquery button on left and right of screen?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am looking at jquerymobile split lists...

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/lists-split.html

Currently, it has:

```
Main middle part, right mini button
```

I want to make it have:

```
left mini button, main middle part, right mini button
```

So the question is:

Is there some way to add a mini button on the left of each row too?

Comment: Is this you what you want?: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/lists/lists-split.html#../../docs/lists/lists-icons.html

Comment: hmm...not really, I'm looking for more like literal buttons on the left and right and not just an image...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use a Grid Layout offered by jQM

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/content/content-grids.html

> **Two column grids** To build a two-column (50/50%) layout, start with a container with a class of ui-grid-a, and add two child containers
>   inside it classed with ui-block-a for the first column and ui-block-b
>   for the second:

```
<fieldset class="ui-grid-a">
    <div class="ui-block-a"><button type="submit" data-theme="c">Cancel</button></div>
    <div class="ui-block-b"><button type="submit" data-theme="b">Submit</button></div>     
</fieldset>
```

Or look into a navbar

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-navbar.html

If you look at the header section it does also show two smaller buttons on each side

- http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0/docs/toolbars/docs-headers.html